# How to change value in an xml file onclick using DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have the following code I have been working on using DataTable. When I click on the ACK button, it updates the DOM but not the xml file. I want it to update the xml file so that anyone else who accesses the site won't have to ACK it again.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var addButton = function(){
        $('#alert-table tr td').each(function(){

            if($(this).index() == 3 && $(this).html() == "0")
            {
                $(this).html($('<input type="button" value="ACK" onclick="$(this).parent().html(1);">'));
            }
        });
    }

        var refreshAlertTable = $('#alert-table').dataTable( {
            "bInfo": false,
            "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/alert_json.xml',
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aaSorting" : [[2, "desc"]],
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if ( aData[2] == "5" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                }
                else if ( aData[2] == "4" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');
                }
            },

            "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
                addButton();
            }
        });

        setInterval (function() {
            refreshAlertTable.fnDraw();
        }, 5000);
    } );
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below :

```
var table1 = $('#youtblename').DataTable();
var pathp = "/server_processing_pie.php";

tablel.clear();
tablel.draw();
tablel.ajax.url(pathp).load();
```